# SQL efficient JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Here's a question I'm struggling about for several days...

Lets assume that I have table A (lets named it Offices) with office name, its location id (city), and the location parent id (region).
office can be related to a city or a region location.

```
officeID | locationID | parentLocationID
    1          207             200
    2          421             400
    3          300             null
```

In addition I have another table named USA_Locations that contains only USA cities' location ids of USA.

```
 locations_ID
    400
    500
    600
```

Now what is the best way to know if an office is located in the US?

I know I can check in the JOIN but this seems to be very slow and cost performance.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM offices o
    LEFT JOIN USA_Locations us ON o.locationId = us.locations_id 
                               OR o.parentLocationId = us.locations_id
```

Any other solutions? 
Thanks, in advance.

EDIT:

In addition (if it helps) I have a table of locations (flat list with location name and locationID)

```
 locations_ID | locationName
    400              A
    401              B
    500              C
```

Comment: A JOIN is perfectly fine,why do you need other solution?What do you mean,slow?

Comment: Yes, too slow (have too many records to check in both tables)

Comment: Unless you have neglected to explain the entire problem, there is no point in using a `LEFT JOIN` - try an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: To improve performance the first step is to check the query plan. You might consider adding an index to the join column in each table if there isn't one already.

Comment: Could you show us the actional execution plan? Or post what indexes you have createad for your table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the offices in us locations this should work better:

```
SELECT * 
FROM offices o
where exists
(select 1 from USA_Locations us 
where us.locations_id = isnull(o.parentLocationId,o.locations_id)
```

you may need to make sure you have indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM offices o 
LEFT JOIN USA_Locations us 
ON o.parentLocationId = us.locations_id
```